# Can an Elder Oblex be subject to an AoE more than once?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, area-of-effect

The [Elder Oblex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/elder-oblex) has the Sulfurous Impersonation feature which lets it create an impersonation of a creature in another space. The feature goes on to state:

> For all practical purposes, the simulacrum is the oblex, meaning the oblex occupies its space the simulacrum's space simultaneously.

In the likely event that the Oblex has multiple simulacrums on a battlefield, what happens if 2 or more of them are subjected to an area of effect spell like *fireball*? Does the answer change for a wall spell like *Blade Barrier*?

Answer (score 3):

#### No.

As you have observed, the Sulfurous Impersonation feature says:

> For all practical purposes, the simulacrum is the oblex, meaning the oblex occupies its space and the simulacrum’s space simultaneously.

Since a spell like *fireball* only damage creatures once, and we treat the Oblex and its simulacrum as one creature, it is only damaged once. *Blade barrier* functions the same way. It can only damage a creature once per turn.

Answer (score -1):

### The Elder Oblex suffers the effect once

All AoE spells AFAIK have a phrase similar to “Each creature in ...” (from *Fireball*). The EO is **a** creature in the AoE.